# Is it possible to have dynamic dropdown inside table using primeNg in Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

The sub-category column need to be dynamically populated based on category column value. When I try to select category value, it populates all the row in the sub-category column instead of the specific row.

Please suggest how to change value of only the specific row?

[image: Table]

```
<p-column field="category" header="Category" [sortable]="true" [editable]="false">
<ng-template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <select [(ngModel)]="item.category" (ngModelChange)="populateSubcategory($event)" [ngStyle]='{"width": "100%","border": "true", "background": "rgba(255,255,255,0)"}'>
        <option *ngFor="let row of categoryList" [value]="row.value">{{row.label}} </option>
    </select>
</ng-template>
```

```
<p-column field="subcategory" header="Sub-Category" [sortable]="true" [editable]="false">
                    <ng-template let-item1="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                      <select [(ngModel)]="item1.subcategory" [ngStyle]='{"width": "100%","border": "true", "background": "rgba(255,255,255,0)"}'>
                        <option *ngFor="let row of subCategoryList" [value]="row.value">row.label</option>
                      </select>
                    </ng-template>
                  </p-column>




populateSubcategory(event) {


this.itemService.getCategory().then(items => {

  var foundIndex;

  for (var key in items) {
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

          for (var key1 in items[key])
          {
            if (items[key][key1] === event)
            {
              foundIndex=key;

            }

          }          
    }

  }

  var foundMember = items[foundIndex];
  this.subCategoryList = [];

  for (var key in foundMember) {
     if (key === "sub-category") {

      for (key1 in foundMember[key])
      {

        this.subCategoryList.push({ label: foundMember[key][key1], value: foundMember[key][key1] });

      }      


      }
    }

});
```

}

Comment: Where's the implementation of populateSubcategory, subcategory html, etc

Comment: I have updated the details. Thanks

Comment: Bad tagging, plwase correct

Comment: I have figured out the solution.I added an option column to the table which will hold the dynamic dropdown values and use that field (item1.option)  as dropdown option.                    
`<p-column field="subcategory" header="Sub-Category" [sortable]="true" [editable]="false" <option *ngFor="let row of item1.option" [value]="row.value">{{row.label}}</option>`.                                             
Is there a better solution for it?